# Selecting a Cell in another Workbook

Tags: vba

So I'm trying to find the cell that contains the String PartNumber in another workbook. I haven't found a way to make this work yet. What am I missing?

```
Private Sub SearchInventory_Click()

Dim PartNumber as String
Dim PartRange As Range

PartNumber = Application.InputBox("Enter the Part Number")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Activewindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Assembly Sheet\Inventory.xlsx")
Activewindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
Workbooks("Inventory.xlsx").Activate
Set PartRange = Workbooks("Inventory.xlsx").Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A:A").Find(PartNumber, , xlValues, xlWhole).Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you have? what doesn't work?

Comment: Run time error '424'
Object Required

Comment: At which line does it happen?

Comment: Set PartRange Line.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to take the value of `Select` as if it was an object (with `set`)  which is illegal in VBA because `select` returns a boolean (which is not an object). Another problem that will arise is if the part is not found `select` will be called on `nothing` which will also break.
You will need to do it in two steps like this :

```
Private Sub SearchInventory_Click()

Dim PartNumber as String
Dim PartRange As Range

PartNumber = Application.InputBox("Enter the Part Number")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Activewindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Assembly Sheet\Inventory.xlsx")
Activewindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
Workbooks("Inventory.xlsx").Activate
'Find but do not select so we take the value of Find
Set PartRange = Workbooks("Inventory.xlsx").Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A:A").Find(PartNumber, , xlValues, xlWhole)

'select only if it found something, tell the user otherwise
If PartRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Part not found!")
Else
    PartRange.Select        
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @litelite yup. This works perfectly. Is there a way I can have show the window scroll to the selected cell.

Comment: @W.Powell Try putting `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` before the if

Comment: @litelite Perfect! Thank you so much!